# Resultado indesejado - Query SQL

Tags: java, sql, jpa

Olá. Estou um problema e não enxergo uma forma de resolver.

Meus dados da tabela **movimentacao**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha **query**:

```
select avg(m.valor) from Movimentacao m where m.tipo='SAIDA' group by m.data;
```

Meu **resultado**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não consigo agrupar a média por data(dia). Mesmo se eu usar **distinct**. Sempre retorna todas as datas. Se caso eu agrupo por titular funciona, menos com data. Isso ocorre efetuando a busca pelo JPA e também via banco de dado.

A tabela foi gerada pelo JPA/Hibernate usando Calendar para a data.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Calendar data;
```

Alguém enxerga o problema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AVG é uma função de agregação, então ela fará uma agregação do valor que você colocou na função. No seu caso a media do valor. O que você quer é agregar a media dos valores pelo dia, da forma como você fez, você estará tentando agrupar por meio da data que é timestamp(Ano/Mes/Dia/Hora/Minuto/Segundo/Milissegundo).

Para agrupar pelo dia, você tem varias formas:

A primeira forma, que eu recomendo, é transformar sua coluna em um tipo Data(Dia/mes/ano)
Utilizando a seguinte anotação:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date data;
```

Para maiores informações: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TemporalType.html

Outra forma é pegar a data por meio de alguma função SQL.
No caso do MYSQL:

```
SELECT avg(m.valor) 
FROM Movimentacao m 
WHERE m.tipo='SAIDA' 
GROUP BY DATE(m.data);
```

Para maiores informações: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151335/select-date-from-timestamp-sql

E por ultimo, a ultima maneira seria pegar via HQL, recomendo criar uma função, ou declarar alguma função para extrair apenas a data, semelhante ao DATE() do MYSQL. 
Para maiores informações: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826241/hql-query-based-on-date-on-a-timestamp-column

Comment: Deu certo. User `date(m.data)`.